# Node.js: How to read variables from the system?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, environment-variables, production-environment

I'm completely newbie with Docker and to make a deploy in production I need to read the "environment" variables instead of a file or instead of the package.json script line from the operating system of the container.

I know how to read variables from a .env file or from the script line but I don't know how to do it from the system and I don't know if its possible to read these variables from the system.

How can I do that? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process doesn't change. You still use the below to read environment variables that the process is running in. [Reference for Node.](https://nodejs.dev/learn/how-to-read-environment-variables-from-nodejs)

```
const envVariable = process.env.NAME_OF_VARIABLE;
```

Setting the variable in a Dockerfile can be done using the below. Docs for this are [here.](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env)

```
ENV <key>=<value> ...
```

Things get more complicated when using things like LXC or Kubernetes though.

Comment: Berger Hi!!! Thanks for your help. But checking the documentation, you write the value of the variable in a Docker file and what has asked to me is to read the variable from the system not from any file. For example, if you write echo $HOME in Linux I've got the value of the variable $HOME. What I need to do is the same but from node. Could I read $HOME variable from system in Node with process.env.HOME?

Comment: @JoséCarlos did you try ? (this is a rethoric question...) => `docker -it --rm --name testnode --env toto=blabla node:latest`. In the node console try to read `process.env.toto` (set on the container at start in my command) and `process.env.HOME` or `process.env.HOSTNAME` (set by the "system"). You get a result for all.

Comment: I will try it!! Thanks!!!